# How to import perl module (xml::twig) in a dancer framework

Tags: perl, dancer, xml-twig

I am working on a webapp using Perl Dancer Framework. I am using XML::Twig in  `lib/myapp.pm` file but it seems to be causing a problem for me:

```
package map;
use Dancer ':syntax';

use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Twig;

our $VERSION = '0.1';

get '/' => sub {
    template 'index';
};

post '/' => sub {

    my $id = params -> {id};
    my $ls = params -> {list};

    my @as = split /\,/, $ls;

    foreach my $a (@as){

        #assemble the epost URL
        my $db = 'gene';
        my $base = 'http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/';
        my $url = $base . "esummary.fcgi?db=$db&id=$a";
        my $docsums = get($url);

        #parse the record
            my $t= XML::Twig->new(twig_roots => { 
              'DocumentSummary' => \&summary
             });
            $t->parse($docsums);

        }
    };

    true;
```

The error it gives is:

```
Runtime Error runtime error Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /Library/Perl/5.18/Dancer/Route/Registry.pm line 125
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You are not turning your myapp.pm into a Dancer app, you are just importing the Dancer syntax. There is a difference. Is that what you are intending to do?

Comment: Runtime Error

runtime error

Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /Library/Perl/5.18/Dancer/Route/Registry.pm line 125.

Comment: @aliocee Please post the actual code you're using; the snippet you've posted doesn't generate that error.

Comment: I think that could be based on the `get` imported from LWP::Simple. Dancer has a `get` DSL keyword (which you actually use). Try `use LWP::Simple ()` and later `my $docsums = LWP::Simple::get($url)`.

Comment: I can't duplicate your issue. Running the code you posted, I get a different error: `Undefined subroutine &MyApp::summary`. This happens because you pass a code reference to `XML::Twig::new` but never defined the `summary` function. Please [edit] your question to include the contents of config.yml and what version of Dancer you're using.